# Customized scan of lists for consecutive values

Tags: python, list

I have a list as follows:

```
A = [3 1 2 3 0 4 3 1 2 3 1 0 0 0 1]
```

Given an initial index (e.g., `id = 5`), I would like to find the index of the last item (`ld`) in the list such that all values between `id` and `ld` are greater than zero (inclusive). Consider this example:

If `id = 5` (`A[5] = 4`), `ld = 10` (`ld = 1`).

```
A = [3 1 2 3 0 4 3 1 2 3 1 0 0 0 1]
```

What would be the most efficient way for doing so?

Comment: Do you know an inefficient way?

Comment: I can write a loop starting from id in order to see where an item becomes equal to zero (the first item after id). I think it might be an inefficient method.

Comment: I don't think there is a more efficient method than to scan the list beginning from `id` until encountering an element that is not greater than zero.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to ensure that I am not missing anything better. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, if you can give us some more insight into how you are using this, we may find much more efficient methods. For example if the lists are large (e.g. millions of elements), and you need to do many queries, one possibility would be to use vectorized operations in `numpy` and get in a few operations _all_ the values at once (e.g. `ld = out[id_]`, for any `id_` s.t. `0 <= id_ < len(A)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a companion list that contains `True` iff the condition (`element > 0`) is met, and add a sentinel (`False`) at the end. Then you can just use `list.index(value, start)` to find the next `False` from a given position. At least, if you are going to do several such "queries" on your given list, you'll have looped only once explicitly (each `.index()` also does an iteration, internally, but faster).

Putting it all together:

```py
p = [x > 0 for x in A] + [False]

# then
id_ = 5  # don't shadow id
p.index(False, id_) - 1
# gives 10
```

#### Addendum

As noted in comments, it could be the case that you are looking for a faster solution for the case of: large lists, many queries for a given list.

In that case, you may want to look at [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/).

Here is an example where we pre-compute (once) the location of all elements *not* greater than 0. Then we can use that repeatedly (and very fast) to find the index of the next element zero or lower. That is a slightly different definition than your `ld`, but you can easily that value (segue: I always favor denoting the end of intervals as the first index after the range --it makes many operations simpler; also it lets you distinguish between empty intervals and intervals size 1).

```py
# preparation: indices of "end of runs of positive values"
z = np.r_[np.where((np.array(A) <= 0))[0], len(A)]

# usage
ld_plus = z[np.argmax(z >= id_)]
```

**Example**

```py
A = np.random.randint(-10, 20, size=1_000_000)

# preparation step
z = np.r_[np.where((np.array(A) <= 0))[0], len(A)]

# example query
id_ = len(A) // 2
j = z[np.argmax(z >= id_)]  # 500006
A[id_:j + 1]
# array([99, 73, 91, 43,  8, 62,  0])
```

**Timings**

For the above 1M values array.

```py
# preparation step:
%timeit z = np.r_[np.where((np.array(A) <= 0))[0], len(A)]
# 3.15 ms ± 34.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# single query:
%timeit z[np.argmax(z >= id_)]
# 41 µs ± 51.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Also, it is nice that `z` contains only the indices of elements zero or less. In the case above:

```py
>>> len(z) / len(A)
0.100292
```

Comment: It looks amazing. My question is what if we have an `M` by `N` numpy matrix (instead of an array with shape 1 by `N`). I can use the above method in a loop for `M` rows separately. But I want to know what would be the vectorized approach for the matrix (if it would be faster in your opinion). Pls let me know if you need further info.

Comment: there are definitely ways to address problems like that. But to be sure of the setup etc. it's best to ask a new question with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you want to do. Or you can search for "run length encoding" and probably find solutions that will be close enough for you to adapt.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that avoids using explicit indexes on the list, only scans the relevant elements and does it once only

```
import itertools as it
from typing import Iterable


def f(iterable: Iterable, start: int) -> int:
    try:
        pos, _ = next(
            it.dropwhile(
                lambda el: el[1]>0,
                enumerate(
                    it.islice(iterable, start, None),
                    start=start
                )
            )
        )
    except StopIteration:
        pos = len(iterable)
    return pos - 1


a = [3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
print(f(a, 5))

b = [3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1]
print(f(b, 5))
```

which produces

```
10
14
```